# Move Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2010, windows-sbs

Anyone have a good link to the best way to move Exchange 2007/2010 off our SBS server onto its own server?

Need the data and all to be moved. Exchange is sucking all the juice from our main SBS server.

Thanks
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a high level overview, I would stand up your new Exchange server and install Exchange into your existing Exchange organisation. Once that's installed you will want to get your routing connectors set-up so that mail can flow between the two servers, so that if someone sends an email to server1, that is actually for a mailbox on server 2, mail can move between the two.

Once you have this set-up you can start using the Move Mailbox Tool to move mailboxes between the 2 servers. Assuming you have everything set-up correctly users should not notice any changes at this point, as they should be able to access their mail through either server.

Once you are ready to decommission the old exchange server you would start re-pointing your OWA URLS and Outlook Anywhere set-up to point the new machine, and ensure incoming email is routed to the new server.

I would suggest if possible setting up a test environment so that you can do a test migration before doing the real thing. Whilst you can do any amount of reading on how it should be done, you won't see all the pitfalls until you do it.

Comment: Thanks Sam, that's really great advice. I'm really nervous about doing this, but your solution seems to take care of most of my concerns.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft's advice to move Exchange is the complete reinstall. But I have good experience with VMWare converter of the physical server to virtual, and remove unnecessary things from it. 
Today's is a good approach to install every server to virtual platform to provide better scalability, and ease the migration between physical servers. (VMWare ESXi is a free good choice)

Comment: He us not looking to move his Exchange server just to a different machine, he is looking to migrate from SBS, where Exchange is bundled with the OS, DC, SQL etc onto a dedicated Exchange server, leaving everything else on the SBS server.